# How to make a Nullable FK EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have to build a Code First DB and want to make a Foreign Key Nullable. But I dont know how to do it because it shows that this field can't be Null.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kr6s.png)

Order_Item:

```
namespace ORDER_DATABASE.Tables
{
    public class Order_Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Product:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ORDER_DATABASE.Tables
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Order_Item> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Column i want to be null is **Product** !

Comment: Please post your error as text as [edit] of your question. Second: I think it's just a typo.

Comment: Ah, you need to get rid of the `?`. Reference types can be `null` by design and don't need the `Nullable<>` or `?` syntax.

Comment: @Stefan thanks :) silly that I did not think of that by myself

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear in your code, you could set the FK field in the `Order_Item` class explicitly:

```
namespace ORDER_DATABASE.Tables
{
    public class Order_Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int? ProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```